# Initialize Global Variable With Function Call Assignment

Tags: c, string

I have a simple program as below:

```
static const char* DeviceID = (char*)"my id";
int length = strlen(DeviceID);
int main(){

}
```

and the compiler throw the following error:

> **initializer element is not constant**

I don't know why the compiler can't understand my statement:
`strlen`'s prototype is like the following code:

```
size_t strlen ( const char * str );
```

Comment: Because it is outside a function? C doesn't have static constructors; functions can only be called from within functions. Call `strlen` where you need it. Or are you using C++? (You specify both tags.)

Comment: Why did you tag this C++ if you're not using a C++ compiler?

Comment: Also, in this particular case you don't even need to call an actual function, if you do `static const char[] DeviceID = "my id";` you can use `sizeof` on it.

Comment: static const char[] DeviceID = "my id";

Comment: static const char DeviceID[] = "my id";

Answer (score 1):

Try `sizeof` which yields a compile time constant

```
#define MY_ID "my id"
static const char *DeviceID = MY_ID;  // no cast needed
int length = sizeof MY_ID - 1;        // sizeof also includes the '\0'

int main(void) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is different with C and C++ when you're trying to initailize global variables.

in C, Rvalue of the global initializing statement should be evaluated at compile time.
for instance,

> 1. **static const char* DeviceID = (char*)"my id";** *<-- compiler can evaluate address of "my_id". so, this is valid.*
> 2. **int length = strlen(DeviceID);** *<-- but this can't be at compiletime. means that, we should run the process in order to know
>      its value.*

But, C++ doesn't care about like above. it can initialize global ones at runtime.
so if you use C++ compiler instead of, errors'll be disappeared.